# Why animations in my app doesn't work when downloaded from playStore but work with AndroidStudio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play, mpandroidchart

My Android app is available since 3 years. 
I make updates regularly.

It contains some animations on views and i use MPAndroidChart library.
Since 2 months approximatively, when i launch my app from Android Studio(on real device or emulated device), animations charts works fine but when i download app from Play Store these animations don't work anymore!
That's weird!!

The method used is ObjectAnimator.start().

Does anyone already have this problem?

Thanks a lot!

This code works fine when executed from Android Studio (on real device or emulated device) but doesn't work when downloaded from PlayStore!

**EDIT : I commented the shrink, obfusciate and proguard rules block in my app gradle file and ..... the problem has disappeared.....!**
So i will not use proguard at all anymore!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in `proguard` 
`-keep class android.animation.ObjectAnimator {;}`

Comment: Thank you, but should i add the line "-keep class android.animation.ObjectAnimator {;}" in app rules file or in lib rules file?